# Meteorjs app - only accessable through appstore/playstore?

Tags: cordova, mobile, meteor

I recently deployed my first ever production application with Meteor. I made it for a client who wanted a Android/Iphone application. Meteor was great for this, since it saved me the hazzle of developing one platform at a time, and especially since i'm working alone.

I am however, a bit.. confused about two things.

1. What prevents people from building their own app against my server by simply outputting `meteor run android-device --mobile-server=https://example.com`?
2. How do i make the phone application only accessable through the appstores as native applications are done?

Answer (score 0):

For making your app accessible only through cordova you can use this neat package `meteor add gwendall:iron-router-cordova-only` [link](https://atmospherejs.com/gwendall/iron-router-cordova-only) or wrap the routing in a inCordova block if you want to do the code manually.

As for someone using your mobile server for running a similar app, (assuming you deployed using meteor deploy on a .meteor subdomain) you would have been asked for your meteor.com password the first time you deployed on that machine. Linking a resource not made from your account shows an error.  Note: Unless you wrap the website to cordova only, someone can still view the app in browser.